# Including a base member doesn't seem to work in Entity Framework 5

Tags: entity-framework-5

here are my entities:

```
public abstract class ResourceBase
{
    [Key]
    int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Resource")]
    public Guid ResourceId { get; set; }
    public virtual Resource Resource { get; set; }
}
public class Resource
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }
}
public class Message : ResourceBase
{
    [MaxLength(300)]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

And then my query is something like this:

```
var msgs = messages.Where(x=>x.Id == someRangeOfIds).Include(m=>m.Resource).Select(x => new
                                {
                                    message = x,
                                    replyCount = msgs.Count(msg => msg.Id = magicNumber)
                                });
```

I am running this with proxy creation disabled, and the result is all the messages BUT with all the Resource properties as NULL.  I checked the database and the Resources with matching Guids are there.

I drastically simplified my real life scenario for illustration purposes, but I think you'll find you can reproduce the issue with just this.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework 5 handles inherited properties well (by flattening the inheritence tree and including all the properties as columns for the entity table).

The reason this query didn't work was due to the projection after the include.  Unfortunately, the include statement only really works when you are returning entities.  Although, I did see mention of a solution which is tricky and involves invoking the "include" after the shape of the return data is specified...  If anyone has more information on this please reply.

The solution I came up with was to just rephrase the query so I get all messages in one query, and then in another trip to the database another query that gets all the reply counts.

2 round trips when it really should only be 1.